# 50% of RAM occupied at the beginning

Tags: 14.04, ram

I am using Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS on a DELL INSPIRON N5050. My problem is that I have 6 GB RAM and from the start of the OS almost 50% of my RAM is occupied. I have to mention that I do not have an independent VGA card. What do you think is the reason that the OS occupies this amount of RAM? Is this normal? I checked the list of my active processes and there are no processes occupying so much memory.

Comment: what is your command to view the processes?

Comment: What does "begging of the OS" mean?

Comment: RAM not used is RAM wasted. If you have 6Gb it should try to use 6Gb. Linux only using 3Gb means you have wasted money for the other 3Gb ;)

Answer (score 0):

It is not normal - it should occupy more. Linux uses any unneeded RAM to copy there files from HDD that it has accessed and expects to access more. It keeps files there until memory is actually needed.
Leave it alone.